# How to Mask a value to mean something else

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure it's so simple and I've tried to find it online.

How do i mask a value to mean something else when it is queried?

I have a select drop down and would like to show 'All' for a value which is really `' '`.

```
Select ' ' from dual
```

How do I mask the ' ' value to actually say 'All' from the user's perspective in the drop down?

Comment: Note that I changed the `psql` tag (which is the default command line client for Postgres) to `postgresql`

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you mean, but maybe something like this:

```
select case the_column
         when ' ' then 'All'
         else the_column
       end as the_column
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on sql

```
Select [mycolumnname] = iif(columnvalue == ' ','All',columnvalue)
from Dual
```

Or you can edit in your front end where you have to condition that if value = '
' change to 'All' before populating the dropdown.

Comment: That's not "SQL" (neither the `iif`, nor the square brackets, nor the "assignment" to a different column)